# how to use bootstrap grid system with all platforms (mobile, tablet, desktop)?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I'm trying to improve my bootstrap skills, i have done xtra small and small but dont know how to do medium and large according to this picture, can somebody help with this one would appreciate, there should also be white space between boxes according to the picture, how to do it with margin/padding ?. [image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
 

 
  </style>
</head>
<body>

   
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6  col-lg-6 mg " style="background-color:red; height:200px;"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-6 mg" style="background-color:blue; height:200px;"></div>
 
 
    </div>   
 <div class="row">
 
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-6 mg" style="background-color:yellow; height:200px;"> </div> 
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-6 mg " style="background-color:burlywood; height:200px;"></div>

    </div>  

  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-6 mg" style="background-color:black; height:200px;"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-6 mg" style="background-color:orange; height:200px;"></div>

    </div>  
  <div class="row">
 
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-6 mg " style="background-color:burlywood; height:200px;"></div>

    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `offset-lg-3` and `offset-md-4` classes for offsets divs.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 offset-lg-3" style="background-color:red; height:200px;"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3" style="background-color:blue; height:200px;"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-6" style="background-color:yellow; height:200px;"> </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 offset-md-4 col-lg-3 offset-lg-3" style="background-color:burlywood; height:200px;"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 offset-md-4 col-lg-3 offset-lg-0" style="background-color:black; height:200px;"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 offset-lg-6" style="background-color:orange; height:200px;"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-6" style="background-color:burlywood; height:200px;"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: col-lg is not looking as that picture

Comment: @waleedd32 Whoops! md screwed it up. Let me fix and update.

Comment: @waleedd32 Updated

Comment: @ Rajender Joshi in the picture there is also some kind of padding/margin between boxes, how to apply that ? –